# Storing data in Apache Kafka as alternative?

Tags: apache-kafka

I develop a distributed system to handle orders and do some calculations within them.

All orders are coming to Apache Kafka, where are distributed among specific services.

May I consider Apache Kafka as persistent database for storing orders data?

I confused, because orders is more fit to store in relation database as MySQL.

How to make decision?

In the feature I would like to make analysis of all orders, and do selection by date, amount and etc, would be it possible to do using Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Apache Kafka for persistent storage.

See [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/okay-store-data-apache-kafka/) which looks at why, [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/publishing-apache-kafka-new-york-times/) for an example of a company doing this in production - and [this talk](https://rmoff.dev/oredev19-changing-face-of-etl) for an idea of why using Kafka as your system of record is actually a really sensible idea when combined with other technologies such as ksqlDB for materialising views off the data as and when required.

There's also [this very interesting talk](https://speakerdeck.com/ept/is-kafka-a-database) from Martin Kleppmann which considers whether Kafka itself can even be seen as a database itself.

---

> How then do the selection data like in SQL? For example I need to get all finished orders or orders paid

Using a stream processor such as [ksqlDB](https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html):

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders_topics WHERE ORDER_STATUS='FINISHED';

SELECT * FROM orders_topics WHERE PAID=TRUE;
```

> I need relation between order and payments

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS O LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS P ON O.ID=P.ORDER_ID;
```

Comment: But how then do the selection data like in SQL? For example I need to get all finished orders or orders paid

Comment: I know Kafka is fit for handling data in realtime, but how to make selections with constant data stored in Kafka? For example if I need relation between order and payments

Comment: I've amended my answer

Comment: So, KSQL works with JSON and I can build SQL select based on JSON fields name?

Comment: Could be better read topic and write data to SQL or Mongodb database?

Comment: Also, can I use KSQL in both modes? Streaming and consistent data?

Comment: ksqlDB works with data in Kafka - JSON, CSV, Avro, Protobuf, etc. Check out the links I provided to get a better understanding of how it works and where it fits.